# creating a byte array from a stream in intersystems' cache

Tags: arrays, caching, byte, inputstream, intersystems

What is the prefered method for creating a byte array from an input stream in intersystems' cache. The method I have tried is to first read the entire file im memory then extract one byte at a time and assign the value to an incremental array

Answer (score 1):

1. Open file as stream using `%Stream.FileBinary`
2. Read part/all of the stream into incremental array.

Note: reading the file by big chunks (use $$$MaxLocalLength) into string and then building an incremental array would be faster than reading symbol by symbol)
Here's a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957854/2425753).

Note2: InterSystems Caché can work with bitstrings. [Documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=TCOS_BitStrings).

What do you want to do with that?